# Can i have a composite index on when using a left join

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, sqlplus

My aim is to use a composite index on the `student` table. The Student table will be inner joined onto the `xyz` table. I created my index on the student table as follows:

```
 CREATE INDEX email_phonenumber_student_idx
  ON student(phonenumber, email);
```

When I run my query

```
SELECT Phonenumber, email from student 
left join enrolment on enrolment.studentnumber = student.studentnumber 
where months_between(SYSDATE, dateofbirth)/12 >= 18 and 
enrolment.studentnumber is null and 
student.phonenumber = '07123456788' and student.email = 'Chris@Lailasman.com’;
```

It works as intended, but the index is not being used as when I `'EXPLAIN PLAN FOR'` the query, I can only see the primary key as the index. Have I created the index on the wrong table? The issue arises is that I wanted to make use of a composite key, however, the joined table does not contain any columns for composite index use.

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1388008413

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |              |     1 |    63 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS ANTI           |              |     1 |    63 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| STUDENT      |     1 |    50 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | SYS_C0022463 |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN           | SYS_C0022468 |     1 |    13 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("STUDENT"."EMAIL"='Chris@Lailasman.com' AND
              MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE@!,INTERNAL_FUNCTION("STUDENT"."DATEOFBIRTH"))/12>=18)
   3 - access("STUDENT"."PHONENUMBER"='07123456788')
   4 - access("ENROLMENT"."STUDENTNUMBER"="STUDENT"."STUDENTNUMBER")
```

Comment: `and  xyz.studentnumber is null;` is in your query but your explain plan doesn't show the filter, am I missing something here?

Comment: I used it to identify rows in the left table that are not in the right table.

Comment: The explain plan doesn't show it, so not sure if it's the same query. Anyway, I have already answered your question. Your query has nothing to do with the index.

Comment: Now I am 100% sure what your doing **is not** what your are posting here. Your updated explain plan and query are completely off in comparison. Could you please post the output from one single Oracle session.

Comment: Hi, I updated the question with the exact query, I truncated the table and added 1 row with an exact match to keep it simple as I just want to see the index working.

Comment: Does the other table also need to have the same composite keys as in the index? So do both tables need to have this composite key that was made in the index?

Comment: No. Unless you want to have a `foreign key constraint`.

Comment: Oh ok, these tables do have a foreign key constraint on the primary key in the student table, could that be the reason why the index is not showing up? The tutor table also does not contain the phonenumber and email columns, could that also be the issue?

Comment: Oracle is already doing a unique index scan off of the `PHONENUMBER` index, which is a very efficient way of getting data. It might help if you explain why you are asking about composite indexes and left joins. Are you trying to solve a real performance problem or is this a school assignment where you must create a query that uses a composite index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as expected. Oracle did exactly what you asked it to do.

```
CREATE INDEX email_phonenumber_student_idx
  ON student(phonenumber, email);
```

You have a composite index on `phonenumber, email`, while you do not use any of the columns in the **filter predicate** of your query:

```
where months_between(SYSDATE, dateofbirth)/12 >= 18 
and  xyz.studentnumber is null;
```

**So there is no reason why Oracle would do an index scan** on `phonenumber, email`. You are simply SELECTing those columns of composite key, not filtering them:

```
SELECT Phonenumber, email 
from student left join Xyz
```

**Index** will be used when you **PROJECT** those columns, not just **SELECT**. The `STUDENT` table as expected goes for a `FULL TABLE SCAN` as it is a plain select and doesn't use any filter on the indexed columns. If you want to see an index scan happening, then add below filter:

```
AND phonenumber = <value>
AND email = <value>
```

Comment: I added a phone number filter however, the index is still not being used?

Comment: @Annon See what I said above and do exactly as said. You have composite index containing 2 columns, so how only one column in filter will use the composite index? I think you need to read documentation and understand how optimizer and index works. **Use exact same columns in filter which you have used in index**. Oracle optimizer will do an index scan. Do it and let me know, also mark it as answered if it helped you

Comment: The problem is still there, I believe I have added exactly what you have told me, however, the index is still not being used. I looked at the documentation and cannot find out why it is wrong. I have updated the question with the new query that was used,

Comment: You are not telling the entire story, as what you are saying is impossible. The query and explain plan you have posted are not at all matching, also your index has no involvement. I am saying it again, you must read more about indexes before asking more questions. Trust me,  once you understand the basics, it will help you in asking questions too.

Answer (score 1):

Your estimated rows are "8".  Indexes are not useful for such small tables.  Oracle knows that so it just uses simpler scanning techniques.

There is an overhead to using indexes -- for instance, often both the index and the original data pages need to be read.  They are useful as the data becomes larger.

Comment: So the index will work, it's just that the table is not big enough for Oracle to make use of it yet? Is that right?

Comment: Well, that's not the reason in this case. OP asked for a plain select, and Oracle does a full table scan as expected. There is no reason to do a index scan when all you are asking Oracle is to select all the rows.