# Unable to have a composite index on when using a left join

Tags: sql, database, oracle, syntax, sqlplus

My aim is to use a composite index on the student table. The Student table will be inner joined onto the enrolment table. I created my index on the student table as follows:

```
 CREATE INDEX email_phonenumber_student_idx
  ON student(phonenumber, email);
```

When I run my query

```
SELECT Phonenumber, email from student 
left join enrolment on enrolment.studentnumber = student.studentnumber 
where months_between(SYSDATE, dateofbirth)/12 >= 18 and 
enrolment.studentnumber is null and 
student.phonenumber = '07123456788' and student.email = 'Chris@Lailasman.com’;
```

It works as intended, but the index is not being used as when I 'EXPLAIN PLAN FOR' the query, I can only see the primary key as the index. Have I created the index on the wrong table? The issue arises is that I wanted to make use of a composite key, however, the joined table does not contain any columns for composite index use.

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1388008413

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |              |     1 |    63 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS ANTI           |              |     1 |    63 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| STUDENT      |     1 |    50 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | SYS_C0022463 |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN           | SYS_C0022468 |     1 |    13 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("STUDENT"."EMAIL"='Chris@Lailasman.com' AND
              MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE@!,INTERNAL_FUNCTION("STUDENT"."DATEOFBIRTH"))/12>=18)
   3 - access("STUDENT"."PHONENUMBER"='07123456788')
   4 - access("ENROLMENT"."STUDENTNUMBER"="STUDENT"."STUDENTNUMBER")
```

Comment: How many rows in your student table? What are the data types of the two indexed columns?

Comment: The student table contains 17 i believe and the enrolment table contains 1. I created a left join on the tables to see which rows are not in the enrolment table that are not 18 and older. The datatypes are varchar(25) for the phonenumber and varchar2(100) for the email. thanks

Comment: Oracle is often not going to use an index on small tables.  There is no performance advantage.

Comment: Would this be the case even when I run the 'EXPLAIN PLAN FOR' statement?

Comment: Change `student.email = 'Chris@Lailasman.com’;` to `student.email like 'Chris%'` and test again

Comment: @Annon: with only 17 rows in one table and a single row in another I would fully expect the database to use a FULL TABLE SCAN on both tables and just iterate through these (very few) rows to find the results. In any case, the plan the database shows you is what it will use for that query. `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR` just stops the database from executing the statement - it will generate the same plan if you're actually executing the statement.

Comment: HOw is is this different from your earlier thread .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61850728/can-i-have-a-composite-index-on-when-using-a-left-join

Comment: It's not, however, the thread got very long and complicated where the answers were not direct, thus it is confusing to people who might have similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `explain` shows what the optimizer will actually do given the current "shape" (size, distribution, etc) of the data.

The most expensive operation for a database is disk I/O. Since you have only 17 rows, the entire table can likely be read into memory with a single I/O operation (typically a 2K page), so it's faster to read the whole table into memory and scan all the rows in memory than go via an index, which would require multiple I/O operations.

You might find the index starting to be used at maybe 1000 rows, but it depends on your schema.

Comment: If the rows are all identical should the index then still work? I created 6259 identical rows, however, the index didn't work?

Comment: @Annon It won't work with identical rows, because part of the analysis of the data is its *cardinality* (the number of different values). Unless there are "enough" (I have heard that `11` is the magic numerb different values, a full table scan will out-perform an index based lookup.